# Why isn't my <p> elements being rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I've just started to learn React and I initialized a todo App using vite. Now I want to know why the paragraph elements are not being rendered on the browser.

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Meu primeiro todo",
    isCompleted: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Estudar francês",
    isCompleted: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Estudar Python",
    isCompleted: false,
  },
];

export function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <h1>Todo App</h1>
        <input type="text" />
        <button>Add</button>
        {data.map((item) => {
          <p>{item.title}</p>;
        })}
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Everything except for the p elements are being rendered perfectly.

I tried changing the map method for the forEach, but it didn't work at all.

Comment: you are missing your return statement in your `map` function

Comment: Don't add curly braces: `{data.map((item) => <p>{item.title}</p>)}`